# Accessing an old Progress v9.1e database

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I have an old Progress version 9.1e Database file that I need to access.

Is there some way to get an older version of OpenEdge to open this? I've had a thorough look at their website and have come up with nothing. I've also researched for two days with no luck.

Any help or insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progress databases don't generally exist in a vacuum.  The system that the database is on should have the executables needed to open it and work with it installed somewhere.

If you have simply copied this db from some other system you are basically out of luck.  And you probably missed key files that are needed.  Especially if you copied a live db.

Assuming that this db still exists on the original system knowing what OS it is would help.  If this is a unix variant "find -name progress.cfg -print" should reveal the installation directory.  Export an environment variable named DLC pointing at that dir -- i.e. export DLC/usr/dlc.  There will also be a "bin" subdirectory.  Put that in you PATH. Then type "showcfg".  That should reveal what licenses you have available -- which goes a long ways towards narrowing down the options available to open the db and work with the data.

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for your excellent reply. We are required to insert data into the Progress database for another client, as one of our systems needs to integrate with it. Is there an 'easy' way to get this done? I apologize for the questions - I'm completely new to Progress(as is everyone at my workplace).

Comment: To insert data you need  to either run a 4GL program or connect via ODBC/JDBC and run some SQL.  Both of those approaches require a running instance of the database.  It sounds like this is a live system so there must be someone (a DBA) in charge of it?  Either that or it is an embedded system at an end-user site with no administrator and probably no idea how to go about it.  In which case you need a lot of outside help.

Comment: It happens to be the second case, where Progress is installed with another system and used at an end-user site. They are of no help to us, and our DBAs haven't worked with Progress before. We've resorted to writing a Linux application to be run on the same machine, pulling and writing the data we need using ODBC. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Given the circumstances that is not a bad approach.  You need to be aware of several things:  0) The Progress db is not a SQL db.  1) Progress will "overstuff" fields.  This gives fits to SQL clients -- you may need to run "dbtool" from time to time to correct this.  2) The SQL engine uses a cost-based optimizer but you must occasionally update the statistics for this to be effective.  Otherwise your queries may be sluggish.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will take this into account during the development process. I apologize for the number of questions or confusion - Progress seems to be very newbie unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need the binaries (and a license code), or know someone who has a copy who'se willing to D&L it to a version you do have access to.

A chat with an PSC sales rep may be fruitful in this case.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you for your answer. I have e-mailed Progress support with no luck yet. They seem to be slow to respond.

Comment: Who did you send the email to Frank?

Comment: Also, does your machine have a development system on it?

Comment: I used the online web form to log a request. I received a confirmation e-mail thereafter and haven't heard back since. I'm not sure about the development system.